# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object I am getting this error

Tags: python, nlp

This is the code for which i am getting error. i have an excel sheet whith 2 colunms column A  contains Urdu Text and column B contains Class of the text True or False

```
counter = collections.Counter()
maxlen = 0
c=0
df=pd.read_excel(INPUT_FILE)
df.columns=['Text','label']
label=df['label']
sent=df['Text']
# print (sent)
content=df
for index, row in df.iterrows():
#   print(row['Text'], row['label'])
    words = [x.lower() for x in nltk.word_tokenize(row['Text'])] # here i am getting error 
    if len(words) > maxlen:
        maxlen = len(words)
        c=c+1
    for word in words:
        counter[word] += 1
print (len(counter))
print (maxlen)
```

I have tried different solutions already but all in vain. Please suggest me some code or solution which is according to my code and my problem. i am using urdu language maybe that is some issue.

Comment: Can you give us where this error occurs? Also could you properly format the code in your post?

Comment: Post the full traceback message instead of a summay. It holds valuable information.

Comment: Victor Douet it occured righte after the for loop, the line starting from "words = [x." this.

Comment: Again, edit your question to include the *full* traceback and the *full* error message, not a retyped or redacted version. In leaving out what seems to you unimportant you limit our understanding of the problem.

Comment: And if you suspect the problem is Urdu... why haven't you tried with something else?

Comment: can you please print the type of row['text']? 
check here, i'm having a feeling that you are not using it the right way.
ref: https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html

word_tokenize(s)[source]
Tokenize a string to split off punctuation other than periods

Answer (score 0):

`"word_tokenize"` takes a `"string"` type as input and you are passing an object which appears to be a different `type`.

Ref to this:

https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html

> ```
> word_tokenize(s)[source]¶
> Tokenize a string to split off punctuation other than periods
> ```